# Missing colourbar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've tried this example from [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_gradient2.html) and it seems `R` is not showing the colourbar(?)

```
dsub <- subset(diamonds, x > 5 & x < 6 & y > 5 & y < 6)
dsub$diff <- with(dsub, sqrt(abs(x-y))* sign(x-y))
(d <- qplot(x, y, data=dsub, colour=diff))
```

that's my R session:

```
R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

[image]

Comment: it works fine, and in fact many people use ggplot2 daily so it's unlikely to be a current bug. You should update ggplot2 and all packages it depends on, crucially, scales. Also R, when in doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to run the code and get the colourbar:

[image]

I am running an even older version of `R`:

```
> R.version
                   _                           
    platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
    version.string R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
    nickname       Masked Marvel
```

**Maybe you need to update `ggplot2`**